# To understand the distance function in (X, || . || ) × ( X, ||. || )

Tags: banach-spaces

A very silly doubt but I don't know what I am thinking. See , book introduced the the notion of inner product and then also defined how we can get norm from it. Then book is saying <.,.> : (X, || . || ) × ( X, ||. || ) $\to$ F(scalar field) is continuous. I don't want proof of this statement. What confusing me is how we have defined distance between two points in  (X, || . || ) × ( X, ||. || ). Means say we have $(x_{1},x_{2})$  and $(x_{3},x_{4})$ from (X, || . || ) × ( X, ||. || ), then what is the distance between them i.e. what I want is what is the distance function in vector space (X, || . || ) × ( X, ||. || ).

Comment: Hint: What is the distance in $\mathbb R$? and what is the distance in $\mathbb R^2$. Remark: more than one distance functions can be defined here. Not really sure whether you need one of them or all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some examples of norm on $X \times X$ are $\|(x,y)\|=\|x\|+\|y\|$, $\|(x,y)\|=(\|x\|^{2}+\|y\|^{2})^{1/2}$, $\|(x,y)\|=\max (\|x\|,\|y\|)$. They all give rise to the same topology on $X \times X$.

Answer (score 1):

Most common norms on the product space are probably those two (equivalent) norms:
$$\lVert (x_1,x_2) \rVert_\infty=\max (\lVert x_1 \rVert, \lVert x_2 \rVert)$$
$$\lVert (x_1,x_2)\rVert_1= \lVert x_1 \rVert + \lVert x_2 \rVert$$
Distance between two points is as usual just the norm of the difference.

Comment: As the comment above sugest: You can also find other equivalent norms in the spirit of the norms on $\mathbb{R}^2$, these two are just very common